# ns_error_net_interrupt in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website deployed in AWS but whenever I use firefox to access my website and make a request, it always blocked the request and throws an error "ns_error_net_interrupt" But when I access my website in chrome, everything is working fine. Is there anyone who has idea of what's going on?
[image: error]

Comment: did you find out what was causing this issue at the end? I'm also experiencing a similar problem

Comment: My company faced an issue when Cloudflare rolled out some new HTTP 3 features. Disabling http 3 on cloudflare resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Firefox has a bug in the http3 handler with some xhr requests.  If you're in AWS and using CloudFront you probably have the default http1.1, http2, and http3 protocols.  I disabled http3 and Firefox requests started working again.

More information:

there is no bug reported, but searching the source code for that error i find comments like [this](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/nsSocketTransport2.cpp#157)

```
case PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR:  // XXX document this correlation
  rv = NS_ERROR_NET_INTERRUPT;
```

and [this](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/docshell/base/nsDocShell.cpp#3885)

```
 if ((NS_ERROR_NET_INTERRUPT == aError || NS_ERROR_NET_RESET == aError) &&
  SchemeIsHTTPS(aURI)) {
// Maybe TLS intolerant. Treat this as an SSL error.
error = "nssFailure2";
```

}